# CFG - whose words contain exactly twice as many b's as a's.

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I am trying to built a CFG for the language that accepts all words that have twice as many b's as a's. The only idea I could come up with is:

Start -> S

S-> SaSbSbS | SbSaSbS | SbSbSaS | $\epsilon$

But obviously it will not be able to parse the word `aaabbbbbb` Because it doesn't matter what combination I pick, there will still be an `S` which can not be parsed further as it will contain either only a's or b's (if I am wrong please guide me how do I parse this word using the above CFG).

The worst part is that googling brought either the [same solution](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa01/cse105_A/105_sol2.pdf) or [something](http://staffwww.dcs.shef.ac.uk/people/J.Marshall/alc/studyguides/Selected_Solutions_2.pdf) similar although written is some other manner, but still unable to parse the above word.

The question is: is there a CFG for the language that accepts twice as many b's as a's (being able to parse the given word) and if yes, what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re forgetting the $\epsilon$-productions. Your grammar does generate $aaabbbbbb$:

$$S\Rightarrow SaSbSbS\Rightarrow^* aSbb\Rightarrow aSaSbSbSbb\Rightarrow^* aaSbbbb\Rightarrow^* aaabbbbbb\;.$$

The first and second $\Rightarrow^*$ use $S\to\epsilon$ three times each; the last abbreviates a longer sequence of applications of productions, but at that point it should be clear what they are.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to see that every word generated by your grammar have twice the number of $b$'s as $a$'s. It is also easy to check that any word generated by the following grammar, can also be generated by your grammar:

$S \to a S b S b \mid b S a S b \mid b S b S a \mid S S \mid \varepsilon$

A less simple to answer question is *Why do these grammars always work?*.

So take any word $x$ of length $n$ with twice as many $b$'s as $a$'s.

One may think of a graph/histogram, where the $x$ axis goes from $1$ to $n$, and on position $i$ we plot a bar of height "number of $a$'s minus half the number of $b$'s seen up to and including position $i$."

We now break the word at the points where the graph touches the $x$ axis (meaning it equals $0$); we will use the $S S$ production to get as many $S$'s as the number of parts we see in the graph. Let us show that each such part can be generated by a single $S$.

If the part starts with an $a$, it must end with a $b$ (otherwise the graph would have crossed the $x$ axis earlier). Then choose the first production $a S b S b$. The $b$ in the middle may be chosen to be the first index $i$ where the graph touches $1/2$. Note that it cannot reach $1/2$ via $-1/2$ with an $a$, without actually touching $0$ beforehand (since one must use $b$ to decrease, each $b$ giving a 1/2 decrement). So there must be a $b$ at that index. Hence the string after the first $a$ and before $i$ begins at and returns to $1$, i.e., it has twice the number of $b$'s as $a$'s; likewise for the string which begins after $i$ and ends before the last $b$; by induction hypothesis, both these strings can be generated by $S$.

A similar argument will work for the other two cases.

So this proof works, but it is long and tedious. Does anyone have a simpler argument?